# PowerShell Supress specific errors from `$Error`

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out how to keep the variable `$Error` clean from `System.IO.PathTooLongException` exceptions but still collect these long paths in an `ArrayList` for later use.

**Example:**

```
$LongPath1 = "\\domain.net\bnl\Other stuff\DEPARTMENTS\SITE\Administration\Plant\Securite\Bien etre\Bien etre\Bien-être au travail\Travaux de fin d'année\Other-Stuff"
$LongPath2 = "\\domain.net\bnl\Other stuff\DEPARTMENTS\SITE\Administration\Plant\Laboratoire\Sauvegarde PC\Bibliothèques\Documents\Sauvegarde dossier Labo\Laboratoire (sauvegarde 03-2014)\Laboratoire\Travaux en cours"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $LongPath1 -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $LongPath2 -ErrorVariable +e -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$PathTooLong = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

$e | where {$_.Exception -like 'System.IO.PathTooLongException*'} | ForEach {
    $PathTooLong.Add($_.TargetObject) | Out-Null
}

$PathTooLong
```

How is it possible to delete the exact same error stored in the `ErrorVariable` 'e' for long paths from the automatically generated `$Error` variable?

**Tried:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $LongPath1 -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction Ignore
```

What I thought would be genius was to use the option `Ignore` so the `$Error` variable doesn't get filled automatically, but then the `ErrorVariable` 'e' stays empty to...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a lot simpler than I thought initially. Here's the answer I found:

```
$LongPath1 = "\\domain.net\bnl\Other stuff\DEPARTMENTS\SITE\Administration\Plant\Securite\Bien etre\Bien etre\Bien-être au travail\Travaux de fin d'année\Other-Stuff"
$LongPath2 = "\\domain.net\bnl\Other stuff\DEPARTMENTS\SITE\Administration\Plant\Laboratoire\Sauvegarde PC\Bibliothèques\Documents\Sauvegarde dossier Labo\Laboratoire (sauvegarde 03-2014)\Laboratoire\Travaux en cours"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $LongPath1 -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $LongPath2 -ErrorVariable +e -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$PathTooLong = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

$e | where {$_.Exception -like 'System.IO.PathTooLongException*'} | ForEach {
    $PathTooLong.Add($_.TargetObject) | Out-Null
    $Error.Remove($_)
}

$PathTooLong
```

I can easily remove errors like `$Error.Remove($_)`. Gotta love PowerShell! :)